# Dealing with null in a case statement on a casted value in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to group a value which is astring of decimals into named groups.

Example :

`CASE WHEN CAST(X as NUMERIC)<1000 THEN "Under1000" ELSE "Over1000" END`

As I've got some values missing, I would rather use safe_cast instead of cast and want a specific group for missing values.

I could go for :

`CASE WHEN SAFE_CAST(X as NUMERIC) = NULL THEN "MissingData" WHEN SAFE_CAST(X as NUMERIC)<1000 THEN "Under1000" ELSE "Over1000" END`

But what annoys me here is that I'm reapeating the safe_cast operation.
Is there a way to avoid that ?

I've been reading following example :

`CASE operation(X) WHEN result1 THEN "result1" WHEN result2 THEN "result2" ELSE "other_result" END`

But that kind of syntax seems to work only for equality operator in the when statements (ie operation(X) = result1 or operation(X) = result2 etc.).

And here I use inferior (or superior)... So I don't know how to manage that.

I guess there must be a way to avoid that operation repetition but can't figure out how.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't use the second shortened version of `CASE`, because it only works with equality checks, and you need an `IS NULL` comparison.  Your current code might already be as tight as it can get.

Comment: oh :( ok :( thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you to avoid writing SAFE_CAST() several times:

```
WITH your_data AS (
SELECT "Bob" as name, "150.19" as weight UNION ALL 
SELECT "Tom", "2000.90" UNION ALL
SELECT "Jerry", Null)

, transform as (
SELECT name, CAST(weight as NUMERIC) as weight
FROM your_data
)

SELECT 
  name,
  CASE
    WHEN weight IS NULL 
      THEN "MissingData"
    WHEN weight<1000 
      THEN "Under1000"
    ELSE "Over1000"
  END as weight_agg
FROM transform
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a syntax-based answer that would help, but one potential way to achieve "cleaner" or non-repetitive code is break up your query into logical chunks using CTEs.

```
with data as (), -- raw data
     casted as (), -- do your safe_cast here 
     transformed as () - do your case statement here
select * from transformed
```

It does make for "longer" code, but it also allows for cleaner logic in the transformation stage (your stated goal).